# How to set MockWebServer port to WebClient in JUnit test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, okhttp, mockwebserver

I'm using `spring-boot` with `WebClient`, which is autowired as a bean.

Problem: when writing a `junit` integration test, I have to use okhttp `MockWebServer`. This mock always starts up on a random port, eg `localhost:14321`.

Now my `WebClient` of course has a fixed url that it sends the requests to. This url may be given by an `application.properties` parameter like `webclient.url=https://my.domain.com/`, so I could override that field in a `junit` test. But only statically.

Question: how can I reset the `WebClient` bean inside a `@SpringBootTest` so that it sends the requests always to my mock server?

```
@Service
public class WebClientService {
     public WebClientService(WebClient.Builder builder, @Value("${webclient.url}" String url) {
          this.webClient = builder.baseUrl(url)...build();
     }

     public Response send() {
          return webClient.body().exchange().bodyToMono();
     }
}

@Service
public void CallingService {
      @Autowired
      private WebClientService service;

      public void call() {
           service.send();
      }
}


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MyWebTest {
        @Autowired
        private CallingService calling;

        @Test
        public void test() {
             MockWebServer mockWebServer = new MockWebServer();
             System.out.println("Current mock server url: " + mockWebServer.url("/").toString()); //this is random    

             mockWebServer.enqueue(new MockResponse()....);

             //TODO how to make the mocked server url public to the WebClient?
             calling.call();
        }
}
```

As you see, I'm writing a full realworld junit integration test. The only problem is: how can I pass the `MockWebServer` url and port to the `WebClient` so that it automatically sends the requests to my mock??

Sidenote: I definitely need a random port in `MockWebServer` here to not interfer with other running tests or applications. Thus have to stick to the random port, and find a way to pass it to the webclient (or dynamically override the application property).

---

**Update**:
I came up with the following, which works. But maybe anyone knows how to make the mockserver field *non-static*?

```
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = RandomPortInitializer.class)
public abstract class AbstractITest {
    @ClassRule
    public static final MockWebServer mockWebServer = new MockWebServer();

    public static class RandomPortInitializer implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        @Override
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext applicationContext) {
            TestPropertySourceUtils.addInlinedPropertiesToEnvironment(applicationContext,
                    "webclient.url=" + mockWebServer.url("/").toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello! Why are you using `MockWebServer` if you want to do an Integration Test? Isn't `SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT` enough for creating a complete web environment (without needing to mock anything)?

Comment: I need to mock the *remote* webserver that is requested within my application. Of course I cannot execute itests against a live remote webserver. So that is to be mocked. As written, I'm creating a *client* application, not a server!

Comment: @membersound Have you tried my solution ?

Comment: As written, I have to mock the **remote** connection that the `WebClient` sends out of my application. This has nothing to do with the `RANDOM_PORT` property that spring starts my own webserver with!

Comment: But you said that your remote server also has a random port. By the way, why can't you try a fixed port ? It doesn't matter for the client but for the server, I think that you can easily find a free and stable port

Comment: Sorry then, I did not mean that, the remote server port is always fixed.

Comment: If it's fixed, why don't you use MockWebServer.start(PORT) ?

Comment: Imagine my remote webserver is accessed with `webclient.url=my.remote.domain:2233`. Now in my integration test I'd have to replace it with `webclient.url=localhost:<randomport>`. Of course I could start the `MockWebServer` on port `2233`, but the next developer who's running the code might have another service running on 2233, so the rest fails as it cannot start the mock server. Or another example, if two applications are running integration test suite side by side, and both by change operating on port 2233. So I'd prefer injecting the random port into the `WebClient` to be 100% flexible.

Comment: regarding making mockWebServer non-static, I am not sure if it is possible because application context is loaded for a test class and then reused for each test in order to reduce the setup costs per test suite. We need to inject early those properties into the environment before the context is initialized for a test suite.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Since Spring Framework 5.2.5 (Spring Boot 2.x) you can use `DynamicPropertySource` annotation which is quite handy.

Here is a complete example how you can use it with `MockWebServer` to bind the correct port:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
public abstract class AbstractIT {

    static MockWebServer mockWebServer;

    @DynamicPropertySource
    static void properties(DynamicPropertyRegistry r) throws IOException {
        r.add("some-service.url", () -> "http://localhost:" + mockWebServer.getPort());
    }

    @BeforeAll
    static void beforeAll() throws IOException {
        mockWebServer = new MockWebServer();
        mockWebServer.start();
    }

    @AfterAll
    static void afterAll() throws IOException {
        mockWebServer.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Comment: DynamicPropertySource will result in instantiation of a new Spring context for each test which can have unexpected side effects like running out of DB connections

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution that's working from me.  Spring Boot 2 & Spring-Webflux 5.3.30 using SpringBootTest

1. MyServiceClientTestConfig creates injected beans port and myServiceClient, where

   - The port Integer bean is generated using Spring's TestSocketUtils.findAvailableTcpPort()
   - MyServiceClient is a Spring service that uses WebClient and gets initialized with a base URL.
2. As documented we should not re-use a MockWebServer instance between tests so create it before each test using the port we found free at test initialization and shut it down after each test.

I suppose there is a slim chance that since I find the port once when Spring is initializing the application context and there are short periods of time where it is not in use by MockWebServer, before the first call to init and between tests, that another process could take the port but the odds of that happening during the lifetime of the test seem incredibly small.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.NONE)
public class MyServiceClientTest {

    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyServiceClientTest.class);

    private MockWebServer mockWebServer;

    @Autowired
    private MyServiceClient myServiceClient;

    @Autowired
    private Integer port;

    @BeforeEach
    void init() throws IOException {
        assertNotNull(myServiceClient);
        assertNotNull(port);

        // MockWebServer not re-usable between tests
        mockWebServer = new MockWebServer();
        mockWebServer.start(port);

        assertNotNull(mockWebServer);
        assertEquals(port, mockWebServer.getPort());
    }

    @AfterEach
    void cleanUp() throws IOException {
        // MockWebServer not re-usable between tests
        mockWebServer.shutdown();
    }

    @Test
    public void placeholderTest1() {
        LOG.info("Hello 1 {}", mockWebServer.getPort());
    }

    @Test
    public void placeholderTest2() {
        LOG.info("Hello 2 {}", mockWebServer.getPort());
    }

    @Configuration
    static class MyServiceClientTestConfig {

        @Bean
        Integer getFreePort () {
            // find a free port to use for this test
            return TestSocketUtils.findAvailableTcpPort();
        }

        @Bean
        MyServiceClient getMyServiceClient(Integer port) {
            return new MyServiceClient(String.format("http://localhost:%d", port));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can set a WebClient base URL with the URL of the MockWebServer.

The WebClient and MockWebServer are light enough to be recreated for each test.

```java
@SpringBootTest
class Tests {

  @Autowired
  private WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

  private MockWebServer mockWebServer;

  private WebClient client;

  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() throws Exception {
    mockWebServer = new MockWebServer();
    mockWebServer.start();

    // Set WebClinet base URL with the the mock web server URL 
    webClientBuilder.baseUrl(mockWebServer.url("").toString());

    client = webClientBuilder.build();

  }

  @AfterEach
  void tearDown() throws Exception {
    mockWebServer.shutdown();
  }

  @Test
  void bodyIsExpected() throws InterruptedException {

    mockWebServer.enqueue(new MockResponse().setStatus("HTTP/1.1 200 OK").setBody("Hello World!")
        .addHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain"));

    ResponseEntity<String> response = client.get().retrieve().toEntity(String.class).block();

    assertThat(response.getBody(), is("Hello World!"));
  }
}
```